# So I want to display the sum of all employees salary in the header and footer of report

Tags: jasper-reports

I am new to JasperReports and iReport designing.

I have table in that I have a column salary and I want to display the sum of all employees salary. for that I took a table from pallet created dataset. It displays the table perfectly, in footer I want to display the sum of salary so I created a variable *SalSum* here is the properties of it:

```
class: java.math.BigDecimal 
calculation: sum 
ResetType:Report 
Variable Exp: $F{salary}
```

The problem is , The sum of salary is not displaying and getting the description as `Variable not found:SalSum` and The table also displays 3 times in report. How to solve this?

I have aleady drag the field to the footer and header but in the aggregiate function i did not see sum fuction.

Comment: Hi, have you defined the variable 'SalSum'?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I just figure it out myself. I created a  variable sum. And i dragged d field i want to sum to my preffered area then den add d variable sum to it as it expression.